# Excel VBA set the BuiltinDocumentProperties for File Description>Comments - set to Read only

Tags: excel, vba

How can I set the BuiltinDocumentProperties Comments of an Excel file to Read only after updating the comments in the VBA code. The user is not expected to edit the file description>comments of the excel file. Note: my question is about the ntfs file properties>details tab>comments (BuiltinDocumentProperties), not excel cell comments. Any help is appreciated.

I have been researching for long :( no luck. I found this link 
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/202068/question-about-document.builtindocumentproperties.security.aspx

, something like this but without ASPOSE

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub ChangePropertyComment()
Dim NewComments As String

NewComments = InputBox("Enter Comments", "Change Comments Property")  'use for dynamic comment
'NewComments = "Read Only"                                         'use for predefined comment

ThisWorkbook.Comments = NewComments
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**APPENDED:**

weak workaround :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()      
ThisWorkbook.Comments = "locked"
ThisWorkbook.Final = True
End Sub
```

good workaround :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
ThisWorkbook.Comments = "locked"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ZAT, But I mean I want want to make it uneditable (file>description>comments). Not set comments to text "Read only". Comments could be anything but it must be locked. I have been researching for long :( no luck. I found this link http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/202068/question-about-document.builtindocumentproperties.security.aspx, something like this but without ASPOSE

Comment: See updated answer. Above all, you can protect your workbook against modifying, but i have not tested that.